# Есть ли в JavaScript качество?

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

В данный момент я занят проработкой метафизики качества, пишу книгу Дзен и искусство ухода из JavaScript. Сам писал на этом языке несколько лет, начать было непросто — пришлось переучиваться. Ранее был опыт программирования на С++.

Во время своего постоянного обучения, мне приходилось много читать форумы и Хабрахабр. Оттуда я и узнал, что JavaScript — некачественный язык, возможно даже не язык программирования вовсе! Что в нем нет этого, того, да и вообще...

Потому, хотелось бы узнать у более опытных пользователей этого языка — есть ли в нем Качество? От ваших ответов многое зависит, в частности — какой будет последняя глава книги.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это можно элементарно проверить!

```js
var JavaScript = ['Качество', 'Качество', 'Качество'];

var haveQuality = confirm('Есть ли качество в JavaScript?');

if(haveQuality){
  if(JavaScript.indexOf('Качество') != -1){
    alert('Вы правы, в JavaScript есть Качество!')
  }else{
    alert('Вы не правы, в JavaScript нет Качества((')
  }
}else{
  if(JavaScript.indexOf('Качество') != -1){
    alert('Вы не правы, в JavaScript есть Качество!')
  }else{
    alert('Вы правы, в JavaScript нет Качества((')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
var Качество = Infinity // Теперь есть!!!
console.log(Качество in (1,eval)('this'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Кармы в нем много хорошей! В Visual Basic гораздо меньше, а в КуМир совсем мало.